# Scheduling a script

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I want to schedule a script at different timings on different day but with a single crontab entry. e.g I want to schedule a script like below:
it should run at

`30 8-5 * * 1-4 script.sh` on mon-thu

and same should run at:

`30 11-5 * * 5-6 script.sh` on Fri,Sat.

Please suggest how to schedule this in one crontab entry.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that with a single entry; why is this a hard requirement ? You can have all these lines in their own dedicated file under `cron.d`, if you're concerned about "polluting" the main crontab file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Just being curious: Is there any advantage in having it into one line, except that it saves you typing "script.sh" twice?

Comment: it is also more clean to have two different lines. Cronjobs should be quite self-explanatory and putting complex syntaxs would stop that.